# Eclipse uninstall

Tags: java, eclipse

I originally installed Eclipse for Devs on Ubuntu (20.10), but later since the decided that EE provides more merits decided to install that.

By the time I made this decision, I was already working on a few projects; hence, didnt uninstall the previous version, but installing over it, hoping it would replace the existing configure, while keeping the projects intact.

Now I have two eclipse, for regular, one EE version.

How can I *completely* uninstall/delete/remove the regular one; while keep the EE, and my projects in place?

As you could see I am not very Eclipse savvy, please answer as concrete as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly did you install the two versions? Projects usually are in separate workspaces and should not be impacted by removing any Eclipse version.

Comment: I installed the version for developers first, then I decided to "upgrade" it to EE version, I assumed it would replace the developer version, but ended up having two different versions. During installation I might have selected different folder for installation, otherwise it *could* have worked. (not sure but it seems that way)

Comment: Yes, but I was asking _how_ you installed each one - snap, apt, manual download...?

Comment: @sebastian: I downloaded zip file to my Ubuntu machines, and ran the installer file to install it. Then, later used the same method to install the EE version. that's how I messed up the Eclipse. It's not completely fixed yet. Now I thing I should have removed Dev version, but when I run the Eclipse, the running application does not show the Eclipse icon, I guess while I was manually deleting it, I might have deleted something all Eclipse share in the Ubuntu. the surviving Eclipse could not link to the app icon file, or it's deleted and it could not find it.